# Is There any way to change Active Directory Users Database Source?

Tags: active-directory, database, synchronization, extension

I need **Active Directory** Use My Own Custom Database (or shell or ...) for Authentication Users.

Is there any extention or something like this to change User Passwords Database of active directory?

I need this Because My Accounts Are In simple Database And I don't Want to Sync them periodically
In Fact I can Not Change all My Applications to authenticate from Active Directory!
Just I need Active Directory to Use My Database For Authentication.

Comment: What do you need AD for if you already have an Identity Database you don't want to replace?

Comment: What problem do you think you're solving by trying to do this? Take a step back and explain your actual problem, I'm **sure** that there's a better answer than what you're asking how to do.

Comment: Agreed. Why are you using AD in the first place?

Comment: You can use any number of metadirectory products to sync, move, slice, or dice accounts - but AD *is*, amongst other things, a user database. You can work with that, but not *replace* it.

Comment: Are you trying to cross-post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920964/how-can-i-connect-active-directory-to-use-from-a-radius-like-freeradius, but with less information?

Comment: Thanks, But Because One of my applications Only support Active Directory and some others does not support It, I need to make single database for Both Of them

Comment: No, you'll need to find some way of keeping two user databases in sync, or using an LDAP passthrough to AD.

Comment: Thanks @mfinni , I am Trying That Way (using an LDAP passthrough to AD).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I uh... uhm... wha... no, please don't do this. Active Directory needs to use ntds.dit and that's that.  NTDS.dit, the Active Directory database, is way more than just a repository of user accounts. Using some sort of custom Franken-database in place of NTDS.dit is nuts, and would in no way be supported by Microsoft at all.  You can do things like [synchronize objects in AD to another SQL database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720650%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), or another LDAP server, but you still must use NTDS.dit.